# How to receive a notification when changes are made to a specific tab in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

If would like to receive an email notification if a new row is added to a specific tab in a Google Sheets.

The default notification rule settings are too limited and the Google Sheets Add-on Store does not provide any suitable add-on script:

[image]

How to send such notifications with a Google Apps script?

Comment: Did you already googled to find the script you are looking for? Do you know how to write a script? What did you already tried?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have searched the Google Sheets Add-on Store but could not find any equivalent. Unfortunately, my knowledge is too limited to write such a script myself.

Comment: Do you know how to write a script to send and email?

Comment: Dear @Rubén, I learned how to write a script that sends an email notification from the answer below.

Comment: That's great!  For your next question, I think that the following will be helpful: [How do I write a great question?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/how-do-i-write-a-great-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) helps here, specifically its changeType property, which tells the script what kind of change happened. If this change is  `INSERT_ROW`, and the name of sheet matches the one you want, then an email is sent using [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app).

```
function notify(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Tracked Sheet' && e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW') {
    MailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Row Added', 'A row was added to your sheet.');
  }
}
```

To use this, add a trigger (Resources > Current project's triggers) with the properties "From spreadsheet | On Change".